Wordpressのインストールが失敗します
環境
Hyper-V (Windows 11)
FreeBSD 14-STABLE
nginx 1.26.1 (HTTP/3対応済）
php82+fpm
mariadb 11.4.2
/wp-admin/setup-config.php?step=2 のURLで500エラーが出ます。
同じことを fpmでなくApache+mod_php82にリバースプロクシをすると正常にセットアップが継続されます。
ちなみにChatGPTに提案され、あらかじめDB情報をwp-config.php に書き込んでも / のURLで500エラーになります。
エラーの詳細については何も残ってません。
UNIXユーザー関係については問題ないはずです。
何が問題でしょうか？

この辺の記事が何か参考になるかもしれません。Nginx, MariaDB and PHP (FEMP)のインストール, WordPress 6.02 + FreeBSD 13.1 + Nginx 1.23.1 + Mariadb 10.6 それらが既読であるなら、どれか(あるいは何か別の記事)を元に作業したのか、何を変えたのかといった情報を具体的に追記すると助言・回答が得られ易いと思われます。

未だに原因不明なのですが、以下を行ったら対処できました
ありがとうございます
gitup ports
portupgrade -aRf
※以下注記 その期間中にクラッキングされていたため再インストール
rm -rf wordpressのディレクトリ
mkdir wordpressのディレクトリ
cd wordpressのディレクトリ
wordpressの展開
